# Usando valores especificos de um JSON do PHP no JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Esse é o meu código, mas por algum motivo ele não mostra o dado solicitado.. gostaria de ver com vocês se estou fazendo algo errado.

PHP

```
<?php
    $var1 = 1;
    $var2 = 2;
    $var3 = 3;

    $myobj -> foo1 = $var1;
    $myobj -> foo2 = $var2;
    $myobj -> foo3 = $var3;

    $json = json_encode( $myobj, true );
?>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    var json = <?php echo "$json"; ?>;

    document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = json.foo2;
</script>
```

Comment: Nào ha a minima necessidade de utilizar formatacao para o que voce está usando na pergunta, favor nao reverter a edicao.

Comment: Realmente, só me dei conta depois hahaha obg

Comment: Notei q voce alterou o codigo, infelizmente minha reversao desfez isso, voce pode editar e corrigir seu codigo novamente?

Comment: Não é necessário tinha tornado uma variável em string sem querer

Comment: Faltam os `;` nos finais das linhas e esse `true` parece ser inválido.

Comment: Os `;` foi questão de desatenção mesmo.. estão corretos no código original.. vou ver sobre a propriedade `true`..

Answer (score 0):

Opa pessoal, acabei descobrindo o erro, o script estava sendo carregado antes do HTML, erro de principiante hahah, obrigado ao pessoal que tentou ajudar!